# Reordering a sql matrix on php

Tags: php, mysql

This is more of a php question than a sql one.

I have a database like this:

```
A B C D E
1 1
1 1 1
1       1
```

I need to order it but not using ORDER BY becouse the parameter needed is not inside the table. I need a sum of several of this numbers "1".

If my requirements needs the fields A, B, C. So the result of the second row is 3, the first row is 2 and the third one is 1.

But if my requirements change for example to just include the field E, then the third row has "1" and the other just have 0.

So I need to sume theese values, something like this:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$ranking = $row['A'] + $row['B'] + $row['C'] + $row['D']
;}
```

I think I need to now insert this new $ranking value inside the $result matrix, and then, sort it using that column and brake it again... But that goes beyond my comprehension of php?

Any light on this please?

---

Edited 1:

Can I do something like this?

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$result = array("$row['A']" => ($row['A'] + $row['B'] + $row['C'] + $row['D']))
;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a simple select query and have PHP dynamically build the sum string if selected columns regularly change. Use the calculated column for your other application needs.

SQL ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/612a4/4))

```
SELECT IFNULL(`A`, 0) + IFNULL(`B`, 0) + IFNULL(`C`,0) As ColsSum
FROM matrix;
```

PHP

```
$cols = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');
$selected = array('A', 'B', 'C');

$colsSQL = "";
$results = array_intersect($cols, $selected);

foreach ($results as $a) {
    $colsSQL .= 'IFNULL(`'. $a .'`,0) + ';
}
$colsSQL = substr($colsSQL, 0, -2);

$strSQL = "SELECT ". $colsSQL ." As ColSums FROM matrix;";

...

mysqli_query($conn, $strSQL);
```

Comment: Great, Ill take a look Thanks!.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need a subquery. A simple select query will do.